# how to use request module to handle cloudflare "checking if connection to site is secure"

Tags: node.js, request

I get `403` status code because i have to do a checkbox verification from cloudflare security middleware. How can I tell cloudflare that I am secure ?

```
 url.net needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
```

I know i need to have a session for that, or use some cookie handler, or whatever it does really. Can somebody give me insight ?

```
const request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')
// Request URL

var url = 'https://www.url.net/';

request(url, (error, response, body)=>{

      // Printing the error if occurred
    if(error) console.log(error)

      // Printing status code
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    fs.writeFile("index.html", body, (err) => {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log("File written successfully\n");
        console.log("The written has the following contents:");
        console.log(fs.readFileSync("index.html", "utf8"));
      }
    });
      // Printing body
    console.log(body);
});
```